# How can I force ReSharper to always put the first parameter on the same line as the method?

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-10.0

In ReSharper, I have "Wrap Long Lines" on, and all "Wrap Parameters" options set to "Chop if long".

If I have a line of code like this:

```
DisplayMessage("This is a really long string that cuts off the screen ...", type, item);
```

ReSharper wants to format the line like this:

```
DisplayMessage(
    "This is a really long string that cuts off the screen ...",
    type,
    item);
```

But I want it to format it like this:

```
DisplayMessage("This is a really long string that cuts off the screen ...",
               type,
               item);
```

Is this possible? I realize that it's because of the long string as the first parameter, so it wants to put it on its own line, but I prefer chopped parameters to be in line with the opening parenthesis.

It's like I need a `[ ] Don't put the first parameter on its own line` option.

Answer (score 6):

The check box you are looking for is placed on:

`Code editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping -> Line Wrapping`

and named

`Prefer wrap after "(" in invocation`

and you want it off

(Yet my Resharper displays 2016.2.2 build 13-Sept-2016 as its version)